Copy a entire row and create 10 new rows with the data from the first row for each row
I need to add 9 blank rows for each row. I can add the blank rows but I would like the data from the row with data to be pasted in each row with a row count added. This will give me a total of 10 rows numbered 0-9 with the same data for each row in my workbook.
I can create the blank row but they are blank. I want 10 repeated rows not 1 with data and 9 blank.

Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Assuming no version constraints per your tags, you can do this with Excel formulas; vba not required:
For flexibility, I created a Table for the original data and Name'd it origTbl
=VSTACK(
    HSTACK("Index", origTbl[#Headers]),
    MAKEARRAY(
        ROWS(origTbl) * 10,
        3,
        LAMBDA(r, c,
            IF(
                c = 1,
                MOD(r - 1, 10),
                INDEX(origTbl, INT((r - 1) / 10) + 1, c - 1)
            )
        )
    )
)



Option Explicit

Sub Demo()
    Dim i As Long, j As Long, k As Long
    Dim arrData, arrRes, iR As Long
    Const START_ROW = 2 ' the first data row#
    Const CNT_ROW = 10 ' quantity of each batch
    Dim oSht As Worksheet
    Set oSht = Sheets("Sheet1") ' modify as needed
    ' loop data into array
    arrData = oSht.Range("A1").CurrentRegion.Value
    ReDim arrRes(1 To UBound(arrData) * 10, 1 To UBound(arrData, 2))
    ' loop through data
    For i = START_ROW To UBound(arrData)
        For k = 1 To 10
            iR = iR + 1
            arrRes(iR, 1) = k - 1
            For j = LBound(arrData, 2) + 1 To UBound(arrData, 2)
                arrRes(iR, j) = arrData(i, j)
            Next
        Next
    Next i
    Sheets.Add
    ' Copy header
    oSht.Rows(1).Copy ActiveSheet.Range("A1")
    ' Write data to sheet
    Range("A2").Resize(iR, UBound(arrData, 2)) = arrRes
    '    ActiveSheet.UsedRange.EntireColumn.AutoFit
End Sub


